# Live plotting using tcl/tk canvas

Tags: canvas, plot, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to plot live changes in a file using `tcl/tk` canvas utility. I have written a simple code to find the difference in file and plot it using `.c create line $oldx $oldy $newx $newy` command.

My code has a while loop to keep checking for changes in the file. When I comment out the while loop, the plot canvas opens fine, but when I uncomment the while loop, the plot canvas does not open at all.

Please suggest edits, the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
#PROGRAM 2 : Print something when a file is changed
#
#package require Tk

#graph prep
 set width 100
 set height 100
 canvas .c -width $width -height $height -background white
 pack .c

#bind .c <Configure> {
#    bind .c <Configure> {}
#    .c xview scroll 0 unit
#    set t 0
#}
#set t 0
#.c create line $t 239 [expr $t + 5] 239 -fill gray
.c create line 0 12 1 13

#Initial reading
 set filename "data.txt"
 #puts $filename
 if [file exists $filename] {
     #puts "file exits!"
    set accessTime [file mtime $filename]
    #puts $accessTime
 }
 #opening file
 set a [open $filename]
 set lines [split [read -nonewline $a] "\n"]
 close $a;                          # Saves a few bytes :-)
 #puts [llength $lines]

 #printing file
 set oldx 0
 set oldy [lindex $lines 0]
 for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $lines]} {incr i} {
     #puts "$i : [lindex $lines $i]"
     set newx $i
     set newy [lindex $lines $i]
     .c create line $oldx $oldy $newx $newy
     set oldx $newx
     set oldy $newy
 }

## after 10000
## #looping to detect change
 while 1 {
     if [file exists $filename] {
    after 1000      
         #  check if new access time
        set nAccessTime [file mtime $filename]
        if {$accessTime != $nAccessTime} {
        #puts $nAccessTime
            #puts "found new"
        #update access time
            set accessTime $nAccessTime
        #read new lines 
        set a [open $filename]
        set lines [split [read -nonewline $a] "\n"]
        close $a;                          # Saves a few bytes :-)
        #puts [llength $lines]

        for {} {$i < [llength $lines]} {incr i} {
            #puts "$i : [lindex $lines $i]"
            set newx $i
            set newy [lindex $lines $i]
            .c create line $oldx $oldy $newx $newy
            set oldx $newx
            set oldy $newy
        }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe it has to do with the event handler, or I think it's name was. Basically, tk elements are drawn only after there are no pending tasks to do and in your case, there is always *something* to do (that includes waiting in between the loops). I would rather put the whole part inside the while loop in a `proc` and call the proc once, and at the end of the proc, use `after 1000 procname` to create the loop.

Comment: @Jerry Easier to use a Tcl 8.6 coroutine. Much easier.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic problem with doing dynamic time-driven updates in Tk (animations have the same issue). The issue is that Tk only redraws itself when the event loop is *idle;* it postpones actual drawing activity until that happens, allowing it to group multiple state changes into one redraw (a vast practical efficiency boost). Most of the time this happens transparently, but when you've got a driving loop such as you've written, you get no updates happening at all.

The quick-hack way of fixing this is to change:

```
after 1000
```

to:

```
after 1000 {set update_ready yes}
vwait update_ready
```

which runs the event loop during the pause instead of stopping the process entirely. Another approach is to instead change it to:

```
update
after 1000
```

but that's significantly inferior because it means that the application is unresponsive during the wait.

**By far better** is to rewrite the code so that it processes the changes in timer callbacks. That's fairly major surgery to your code… unless you have Tcl 8.6, when you can use a coroutine to do it easily:

```
 package require Tcl 8.6;    # <<<< GOOD STYLE
 package require Tk;         # <<<< GOOD STYLE

 set width 100
 set height 100
 canvas .c -width $width -height $height -background white
 pack .c

.c create line 0 12 1 13

#Initial reading
 set filename "data.txt"
 #puts $filename
 if [file exists $filename] {
     #puts "file exits!"
    set accessTime [file mtime $filename]
    #puts $accessTime
 }
 #opening file
 set a [open $filename]
 set lines [split [read -nonewline $a] "\n"]
 close $a;                          # Saves a few bytes :-)
 #puts [llength $lines]

 #printing file
 set oldx 0
 set oldy [lindex $lines 0]
 for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $lines]} {incr i} {
     #puts "$i : [lindex $lines $i]"
     set newx $i
     set newy [lindex $lines $i]
     .c create line $oldx $oldy $newx $newy
     set oldx $newx
     set oldy $newy
 }

## #looping to detect change
coroutine mainloop apply {{} {         # <<< CHANGED LINE
    global i filename accessTime oldx oldy
    while 1 {
        after 1000 [info coroutine];   # <<< CHANGED LINE
        yield;                         # <<< CHANGED LINE

        if {[file exists $filename]} {
            #  check if new access time
            set nAccessTime [file mtime $filename]
            if {$accessTime != $nAccessTime} {
                #puts $nAccessTime
                #puts "found new"
                #update access time
                set accessTime $nAccessTime
                #read new lines 
                set a [open $filename]
                set lines [split [read -nonewline $a] "\n"]
                close $a;                          # Saves a few bytes :-)
                #puts [llength $lines]

                for {} {$i < [llength $lines]} {incr i} {
                    #puts "$i : [lindex $lines $i]"
                    set newx $i
                    set newy [lindex $lines $i]
                    .c create line $oldx $oldy $newx $newy
                    set oldx $newx
                    set oldy $newy
                }
            }
         }
     }
}}
```

You probably also want the delay before the check if the file exists, so that a non-existent file doesn't result in you hammering the OS.

Comment: Thanks Donal. The graph is coming up now, but it not getting updated with the new values in file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured out. i was not added to the global variables list. `global i filename accessTime oldx oldy` worked.

Comment: @guptasonal I've edited that into my answer; I'd just missed that that was used that way here…